# Having Trouble Setting Up Velocity Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity, velocity.js

I'm trying to use Velocity Js for the first time and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Below is a nav menu that I'm trying to create. Everything in the code works fine except for the Velocity Js bits. The animation for the menu even works, but the menu doesn't open. I included both links that the Velocity JS site told me to include, as well as a page link to velocity.min. js. I tried using one or the other, or both, and nothing worked. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Testing Velocity JS</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
    <scrpt src="velocity.min.js"></scrpt>
    <script src="navmenutest.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>document.body.classList.add('fade');</script>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="overlay-navigation">
            <nav role="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="gallery" data-content="Gallery Test">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog" data-content="Blog Test">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about" data-content="About Test">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact" data-content="Contact Test">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="custompcs" data-content="Custom PC's Test">Custom PC's</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <section class="home">
            <div class="open-overlay">
                <span class="bar-top"></span>
                <span class="bar-middle"></span>
                <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
            </div>
        </section>
```

JS:

```
     $('.open-overlay').click(function() {
   $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
   var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
     top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
     middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
     bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

   overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
   if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {

     top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
     middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
     bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
     overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down')
     overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.slideLeftIn', {
       duration: 300,
       delay: 0,
       begin: function() {
         $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveLeftIn', {
           stagger: 150,
           delay: 0,
           complete: function() {
             $('nav ul li a').velocity({
               opacity: [1, 0],
             }, {
               delay: 10,
               duration: 140
             });
             $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
           }
         })
       }
     })

   } else {
     $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
     top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
     middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
     bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
     overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up')
     $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveRightOut', {
       stagger: 150,
       delay: 0,
       complete: function() {
         overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.fadeOut', {
           delay: 0,
           duration: 300,
           complete: function() {
             $('nav ul li a').velocity({
               opacity: [0, 1],
             }, {
               delay: 0,
               duration: 50
             });
             $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
           }
         });
       }
     })
   }
 })
```

Comment: See this blog for setting up velocity.

http://www.independent-software.com/velocity-js-tutorial-accelerated-javascript-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

You misspell the scrpt keyword, It should be script.

```
<script src="velocity.min.js"></script>
```